# Play reverse routing without a Request instance

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using a template to generate an email in Play. That email includes an URL which is generated through [reverse routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing) :

```
<a href="@routes.MyController.downloadFile(user).absoluteURL()">
```

The problem is, the `downloadFile` function takes an `implicit request: Request` parameter (as any `Action`) and I don't always have a `Request` when I'm sending an email (it can be triggered out of a request/response workflow).

Is there some way to obtain the reverse route anyway ? Or maybe should I pass it a dummy request object (and then, how to generate one ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implicit request is not available, you should use method described below defined in `play.mvc.Call` (`play.api.mvc.Call` returned by reverse router extends java `play.mvc.Call` class, so there is no additional work needed):

```java
/**
 * Transform this call to an absolute URL.
 *
 * @param secure true if the absolute URL should use HTTPS protocol instead of HTTP
 * @param host the absolute URL's domain
 * @return the absolute URL string
 */
 public String absoluteURL(boolean secure, String host)
```

Example view code:

```
@(secure: Boolean, host: String)
<a href="@routes.MyController.downloadFile(user).absoluteURL(secure, host)">
```

`secure` and `host` values could be obtained from request or defined somewhere in application configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting [`FakeRequest`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/test/FakeRequest$.html) on the compile classpath

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0"
```

and then provide it as a default `request` parameter to the template

```
@(foo: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader = play.api.test.FakeRequest())
```

Comment: I'd rather not import `play.api.test` things in production.